# How to ignore all hosts that give errors

Tags: python, proxy, mitmproxy

I am just getting my head around using mitmproxy and wanted to know how to ignore hosts that the proxy cannot connect to due to errors such as certificate pinning?

I am aware of the `--ignore-hosts` option but that would require me to list every single host with an error I come across during testing. Is there not a more elegant way whereby any host that doesn't work due to an error can just bypass the proxy?

Just to be clear, I am not after general error handling in Python but rather how to bypass hosts that give errors when connecting via the mitmproxy.